# Multiple devices act as one device for internet

Tags: networking, router, wireless-networking, internet-connection

My landlord only allows a maximum of six connected devices in a house for the internet (two for each tenant). I'm in need of three devices (raspberry pi, laptop and phone). My landlord says I can try to find a way to bypass it because apparently he doesn't know how to do it himself without a costumer support person. So, I'm wondering how I can bypass this restriction, maybe by having multiple devices act as one device?

I've read about access points, so maybe I can use an old router as one device and then connect things to my access point?

Is this something that would work? Are there ways to bypass this six connected device limit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use a wifi capable router to accomplish this. The router would connect to your landlord's network and you would connect all of your devices to the router. Because it would use Network Address Translation, your landlord would only see one device (the router) and none of the devices sitting behind it.